# handling cssRules with javascript properly

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am handling CSS rules using Javascript where on every resize event I create a class which might already be defined in CSS or by previous Javascript resize event, which leads to having too many CSS rules after some resize events. How do I change my code so that either I delete pre-existing CSS rules or modify them.

here is my code that I found on StackOverflow.

```
var setStyleRule = function(selector, rule) {
    var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[(document.styleSheets.length - 1)];
    if(stylesheet.addRule) {
        stylesheet.addRule(selector, rule)
    } else if(stylesheet.insertRule) {
        stylesheet.insertRule(selector + ' { ' + rule + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve exactly? Modifying stylesheets dynamically is a pretty arcane thing to do, and there may well be better solutions. Can you show us the kind of rules you are trying to create?

Comment: @torazaburo i agree, and it was six months ago that i was trying having a solution for was like inventing wheel from the scratch. but its solved long ago and answer below is exactly what i did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an empty style tag to your page with some id like --

```
<style id="customstyles"  type="text/css"></style>
```

and then under resize event handler-

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if (sheet.ownerNode.id == "customstyles") {
        var rules = sheet.cssRules;
        if (rules.length > 0) {
            // instead of addRule, modify the existing rule with following code-
            var style = "css attribute on which you are applying new value";
            var stylevalue = "the value to be applied";
            for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
                var rule = rules[j];
                if (rule.selectorText == selector) {
                    rule.style.setProperty(style, stylevalue);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // call you code to insert new cssRule
            stylesheet.insertRule(selector + ' { ' + rule + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I solved it months ago exactly how you are suggesting, let's hope it will help someone else too.

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ yep.. I know I am a late.. I am fighting with a similar issue.. mean while i found this question unanswered.. may be you can help me with this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747437/